# Subclassing SparkException doesn't allow for message passing between Master and Workers

Tags: scala, exception, apache-spark

I need to build an application where a master node distributes a large dataset to a number of worker nodes for parallel processing. I'm running this application on a single machine and JVM, therefore I've called `setMaster("local[4]")` on my `SparkConf` object. I'm using Spark 1.5.2 and Scala 2.10.5 through IntelliJ.

If a certain condition occurs in the portions of the dataset handled by the executors, I need the master node to be notified and perform some action. In addition to that, I need the other executors to die. To that end, I looked around the Scala Spark API and realized that `SparkException` allows me to do the first portion of what I'm looking for, by propagating the exception (which is `Serializable`, by the way) to the driver. I have verified this experimentally, as follows:

```
def main(args:Array[String]) = {
    val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Spark Exceptions").setMaster("local[4]")
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
    val l = Range(1, 5000)
    val parl = sc.parallelize(l, 8);
    val mappedRDD = parl.map(func)
    try {
        val res = mappedRDD.collect()
        println(res)
    } catch {
        case s:SparkException => println("A worker threw an exception.")
        case t:Throwable => throw(t)
    }
}

def func(i:Int) = {
    if(i == 1 || i == 4000)
        throw new SparkException("Bad number detected.")
    else
        Math.pow(i, 2)
}
```

If you look closely at the example above, you will note that since the original `Range` contains both 1 and 4000, two failures are guaranteed in the worker nodes. Indeed, I see two executors failing in `stderr`, while my `stdout` is populated with:

```
A worker threw an exception.

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Unfortunately, the `SparkException` thrown does not kill the other executors, since, as mentioned before, I can see both executors failing in `stderr`, while two other executors complete their tasks successfully. So my first question is: **is there any way I can immediately kill the other executors once this exception is caught by the driver program?**

My second question is a little bit more subtle: I'd like some information to be exchanged from the executors to the worker node about what piece of information caused the error. Sure, I could write to and read from a file, particularly since I'm on the same filesystem, but I'd like a faster and more elegant solution. So I thought I'd subclass `SparkException` in order to add a field that described what piece of data caused the error:

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkException

class WorkerViolation(msg:String, data:Any) extends SparkException(msg) {
    override def toString = "A worker violation occurred: " + msg
    def getData = data
    def this(dat:Any) = this("Error at worker.", dat)
}
```

The goal is to be able to use the `getData` accessor to retrieve some information. To that end, I tried modifying the program above, as follows:

```
...
catch {
            case w:WorkerViolation => println("A worker threw an exception, with data: " + w.getData)
            case t:Throwable => throw(t)
        }
    }

def func(i:Int) = {
    if(i == 1 || i == 4000)
        throw new WorkerViolation("Bad number detected.", i)
    else
        Math.pow(i, 2)
}
```

Note that this time I'm both throwing and catching `WorkerViolation`s. Unfortunately, this particular exception seems to be killing the driver node as well. The full trace is of course gigantic, yet copied for consistency:

```
15/12/07 18:31:17 WARN util.Utils: Your hostname, debian resolves to a loopback address: 127.0.1.1; using 192.168.2.222 instead (on interface eth0)
15/12/07 18:31:17 WARN util.Utils: Set SPARK_LOCAL_IP if you need to bind to another address
15/12/07 18:31:17 INFO spark.SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: jason
15/12/07 18:31:17 INFO spark.SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users with view permissions: Set(jason)
15/12/07 18:31:17 INFO slf4j.Slf4jLogger: Slf4jLogger started
15/12/07 18:31:17 INFO Remoting: Starting remoting
15/12/07 18:31:17 INFO Remoting: Remoting started; listening on addresses :[akka.tcp://spark@192.168.2.222:33572]
15/12/07 18:31:17 INFO Remoting: Remoting now listens on addresses: [akka.tcp://spark@192.168.2.222:33572]
15/12/07 18:31:17 INFO spark.SparkEnv: Registering MapOutputTracker
15/12/07 18:31:17 INFO spark.SparkEnv: Registering BlockManagerMaster
15/12/07 18:31:17 INFO storage.DiskBlockManager: Created local directory at /tmp/spark-local-20151207183117-4300
15/12/07 18:31:17 INFO storage.MemoryStore: MemoryStore started with capacity 2.1 GB.
15/12/07 18:31:17 INFO network.ConnectionManager: Bound socket to port 34704 with id = ConnectionManagerId(192.168.2.222,34704)
15/12/07 18:31:17 INFO storage.BlockManagerMaster: Trying to register BlockManager
15/12/07 18:31:17 INFO storage.BlockManagerInfo: Registering block manager 192.168.2.222:34704 with 2.1 GB RAM
15/12/07 18:31:17 INFO storage.BlockManagerMaster: Registered BlockManager
15/12/07 18:31:17 INFO spark.HttpServer: Starting HTTP Server
15/12/07 18:31:17 INFO server.Server: jetty-8.1.14.v20131031
15/12/07 18:31:17 INFO server.AbstractConnector: Started SocketConnector@0.0.0.0:42426
15/12/07 18:31:17 INFO broadcast.HttpBroadcast: Broadcast server started at http://192.168.2.222:42426
15/12/07 18:31:17 INFO spark.HttpFileServer: HTTP File server directory is /tmp/spark-0ae72587-14c5-4bfe-a151-2bcafc889ee8
15/12/07 18:31:17 INFO spark.HttpServer: Starting HTTP Server
15/12/07 18:31:17 INFO server.Server: jetty-8.1.14.v20131031
15/12/07 18:31:17 INFO server.AbstractConnector: Started SocketConnector@0.0.0.0:55556
15/12/07 18:31:17 INFO server.Server: jetty-8.1.14.v20131031
15/12/07 18:31:17 INFO server.AbstractConnector: Started SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:4040
15/12/07 18:31:17 INFO ui.SparkUI: Started SparkUI at http://192.168.2.222:4040
15/12/07 18:31:18 INFO spark.SparkContext: Starting job: collect at SparkExceptions.scala:16
15/12/07 18:31:18 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Got job 0 (collect at SparkExceptions.scala:16) with 8 output partitions (allowLocal=false)
15/12/07 18:31:18 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Final stage: Stage 0(collect at SparkExceptions.scala:16)
15/12/07 18:31:18 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Parents of final stage: List()
15/12/07 18:31:18 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Missing parents: List()
15/12/07 18:31:18 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Submitting Stage 0 (MappedRDD[1] at map at SparkExceptions.scala:14), which has no missing parents
15/12/07 18:31:18 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Submitting 8 missing tasks from Stage 0 (MappedRDD[1] at map at SparkExceptions.scala:14)
15/12/07 18:31:18 INFO scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl: Adding task set 0.0 with 8 tasks
15/12/07 18:31:18 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Starting task 0.0:0 as TID 0 on executor localhost: localhost (PROCESS_LOCAL)
15/12/07 18:31:18 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Serialized task 0.0:0 as 1350 bytes in 4 ms
15/12/07 18:31:18 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Starting task 0.0:1 as TID 1 on executor localhost: localhost (PROCESS_LOCAL)
15/12/07 18:31:18 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Serialized task 0.0:1 as 1350 bytes in 0 ms
15/12/07 18:31:18 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Starting task 0.0:2 as TID 2 on executor localhost: localhost (PROCESS_LOCAL)
15/12/07 18:31:18 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Serialized task 0.0:2 as 1350 bytes in 0 ms
15/12/07 18:31:18 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Starting task 0.0:3 as TID 3 on executor localhost: localhost (PROCESS_LOCAL)
15/12/07 18:31:18 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Serialized task 0.0:3 as 1350 bytes in 1 ms
15/12/07 18:31:18 INFO executor.Executor: Running task ID 3
15/12/07 18:31:18 INFO executor.Executor: Running task ID 1
15/12/07 18:31:18 INFO executor.Executor: Running task ID 0
15/12/07 18:31:18 INFO executor.Executor: Running task ID 2
15/12/07 18:31:18 ERROR executor.Executor: Exception in task ID 0
A worker violation occurred: Bad number detected.
    at SparkExceptions$.func(SparkExceptions.scala:26)
    at SparkExceptions$$anonfun$1.apply$mcDI$sp(SparkExceptions.scala:14)
    at SparkExceptions$$anonfun$1.apply(SparkExceptions.scala:14)
    at SparkExceptions$$anonfun$1.apply(SparkExceptions.scala:14)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at scala.collection.generic.Growable$class.$plus$plus$eq(Growable.scala:48)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:103)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.to(TraversableOnce.scala:273)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.to(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toBuffer(TraversableOnce.scala:265)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toBuffer(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toArray(TraversableOnce.scala:252)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toArray(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$15.apply(RDD.scala:717)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$15.apply(RDD.scala:717)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$4.apply(SparkContext.scala:1083)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$4.apply(SparkContext.scala:1083)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:111)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:51)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:183)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
15/12/07 18:31:18 INFO executor.Executor: Serialized size of result for 2 is 5565
15/12/07 18:31:18 INFO executor.Executor: Serialized size of result for 1 is 5565
15/12/07 18:31:18 INFO executor.Executor: Sending result for 2 directly to driver
15/12/07 18:31:18 INFO executor.Executor: Sending result for 1 directly to driver
15/12/07 18:31:18 INFO executor.Executor: Serialized size of result for 3 is 5565
15/12/07 18:31:18 INFO executor.Executor: Finished task ID 2
15/12/07 18:31:18 INFO executor.Executor: Finished task ID 1
15/12/07 18:31:18 INFO executor.Executor: Sending result for 3 directly to driver
15/12/07 18:31:18 INFO executor.Executor: Finished task ID 3
15/12/07 18:31:18 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Starting task 0.0:4 as TID 4 on executor localhost: localhost (PROCESS_LOCAL)
15/12/07 18:31:18 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Serialized task 0.0:4 as 1350 bytes in 0 ms
15/12/07 18:31:18 INFO executor.Executor: Running task ID 4
15/12/07 18:31:18 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Starting task 0.0:5 as TID 5 on executor localhost: localhost (PROCESS_LOCAL)
15/12/07 18:31:18 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Serialized task 0.0:5 as 1350 bytes in 1 ms
15/12/07 18:31:18 INFO executor.Executor: Running task ID 5
15/12/07 18:31:18 WARN scheduler.TaskSetManager: Lost TID 0 (task 0.0:0)
15/12/07 18:31:18 INFO executor.Executor: Serialized size of result for 4 is 5565
15/12/07 18:31:18 INFO executor.Executor: Sending result for 4 directly to driver
15/12/07 18:31:18 INFO executor.Executor: Finished task ID 4
15/12/07 18:31:18 WARN scheduler.TaskSetManager: Loss was due to helpers.WorkerViolation
A worker violation occurred: Bad number detected.
    at SparkExceptions$.func(SparkExceptions.scala:26)
    at SparkExceptions$$anonfun$1.apply$mcDI$sp(SparkExceptions.scala:14)
    at SparkExceptions$$anonfun$1.apply(SparkExceptions.scala:14)
    at SparkExceptions$$anonfun$1.apply(SparkExceptions.scala:14)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at scala.collection.generic.Growable$class.$plus$plus$eq(Growable.scala:48)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:103)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.to(TraversableOnce.scala:273)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.to(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toBuffer(TraversableOnce.scala:265)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toBuffer(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toArray(TraversableOnce.scala:252)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toArray(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$15.apply(RDD.scala:717)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$15.apply(RDD.scala:717)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$4.apply(SparkContext.scala:1083)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$4.apply(SparkContext.scala:1083)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:111)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:51)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:183)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
15/12/07 18:31:18 INFO executor.Executor: Serialized size of result for 5 is 5565
15/12/07 18:31:18 INFO executor.Executor: Sending result for 5 directly to driver
15/12/07 18:31:18 INFO executor.Executor: Finished task ID 5
15/12/07 18:31:18 ERROR scheduler.TaskSetManager: Task 0.0:0 failed 1 times; aborting job
15/12/07 18:31:18 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Finished TID 2 in 27 ms on localhost (progress: 1/8)
15/12/07 18:31:18 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Finished TID 1 in 30 ms on localhost (progress: 2/8)
15/12/07 18:31:18 INFO scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl: Cancelling stage 0
15/12/07 18:31:18 INFO scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl: Stage 0 was cancelled
15/12/07 18:31:18 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Finished TID 4 in 11 ms on localhost (progress: 3/8)
15/12/07 18:31:18 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Failed to run collect at SparkExceptions.scala:16
15/12/07 18:31:18 INFO scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl: Removed TaskSet 0.0, whose tasks have all completed, from pool 
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0.0:0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Exception failure in TID 0 on host localhost: A worker violation occurred: Bad number detected.
        SparkExceptions$.func(SparkExceptions.scala:26)
        SparkExceptions$$anonfun$1.apply$mcDI$sp(SparkExceptions.scala:14)
        SparkExceptions$$anonfun$1.apply(SparkExceptions.scala:14)
        SparkExceptions$$anonfun$1.apply(SparkExceptions.scala:14)
        scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)
        scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)
        scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1157)
        scala.collection.generic.Growable$class.$plus$plus$eq(Growable.scala:48)
        scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:103)
        scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
        scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.to(TraversableOnce.scala:273)
        scala.collection.AbstractIterator.to(Iterator.scala:1157)
        scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toBuffer(TraversableOnce.scala:265)
        scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toBuffer(Iterator.scala:1157)
        scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toArray(TraversableOnce.scala:252)
        scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toArray(Iterator.scala:1157)
        org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$15.apply(RDD.scala:717)
        org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$15.apply(RDD.scala:717)
        org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$4.apply(SparkContext.scala:1083)
        org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$4.apply(SparkContext.scala:1083)
        org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:111)
        org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:51)
        org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:183)
        java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1044)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1028)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1026)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1026)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:634)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:634)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:236)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:634)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessActor$$anonfun$receive$2.applyOrElse(DAGScheduler.scala:1229)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:498)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:456)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:237)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:219)
    at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:386)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
15/12/07 18:31:18 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Finished TID 5 in 11 ms on localhost (progress: 4/8)
15/12/07 18:31:18 INFO scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl: Removed TaskSet 0.0, whose tasks have all completed, from pool 
15/12/07 18:31:18 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Finished TID 3 in 34 ms on localhost (progress: 5/8)
15/12/07 18:31:18 INFO scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl: Removed TaskSet 0.0, whose tasks have all completed, from pool 

Process finished with exit code 1
```

So my second question would then be: **Why does throwing an exception of a class derived from `SparkException` kill the driver program as well? Is there a different strategy I can use for executor-driver communication?**

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, I have decided that in order to allow for a higher degree of message-passing between nodes, going down to the level of [akka actors](http://akka.io/) is the preferred way to go.